# Want to know the name of an old movie about alien infiltration

Tags: movie, aliens

I saw a SF movie when I was a kid, in 1984, but I couldn´t find its name. It was about humanoid aliens visiting Earth. Perhaps a subtle invasion or infiltration.

It was a long time ago, but I recall the aliens` faces were pale.

The ending was pacific, because I recall the movie finished with the alien leader and the human hero agreeing in a handshake.

The movie from the 1965-1984 period.

Anybody knows the title of the movie?

Comment: Duplicate of [Movie where pale humanoid aliens visit Earth and make a pact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228308/movie-where-pale-humanoid-aliens-visit-earth-and-make-a-pact) - please don't repost the same question. Instead, edit it (like you did) and wait to see if other members of the community deem it detailed enough to be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possibly *[The Monitors](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064684)*?  Aliens (not terribly pale, but somewhat) who come down to earth to try to help it.  In the end, they leave, with a handshake:

[image]

You can see the movie [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz4IoF2U_DI).

Comment: Thank you very much. But it´s not the same movie. I recall the handshake between the human hero and the alien leader was at the very end of the movie. I saw it in TV, in 1984, so it was filmed before that year. I´ve searched a lot in IMDB, without results.

Comment: What made the movie so memorable to you, other than the handshake?

Comment: Well, it´s not a merit of the movie itself. I saw it with my father when I was a kid. He passed away last year, and I would be happy to see again the movie I shared with him.

Comment: @ArlettaS i think that comment was meant for you